# Python list comprehension (Euler project 5)

Tags: python, list

```
x = False
divisors = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range (10,10000,10):
    if [x for x in divisors if i % x == 0]:
        print(i)
        break
```

Can I get some pointers as to why this program prints 10? It should print.. 2520

I've spent so much time on this problem now, I guess I don't really understand the list comprehension, how it works, what it returns.

I was hoping the if sentence would yield false if **any** of the divisions yield a float..

Do I need to use casting?

Am I right in that range (10,10000,10) gives a list of 10, 20, 30, 40,..., 10000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it to the following:

```
divisors = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range (10,10000,10):
    if all(i % x == 0 for x in divisors):
         print(i)
         break
```

The list comprehension in your current version will always contain at last 3 values in it, since every multiple of 10 is evenly divisible by 2, 5, and 10.  A non-empty list evaluates as true in a Boolean context, so you will enter the if block on the first iteration.

The built-in function `all()` accepts an iterable and returns `True` only if every element is true (or evaluates as true in a Boolean context).  So it is perfect for determining if `i` is evenly divisible by **all** values in `divisors`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that certainly worked, prints 2520 and everything. Yes I didn't know how to apply AND logic to my if evaluation, I think I need to get hold of a proper up to date book on Python.

Answer (score 3):

Let's decompose that. To start with,

```
x = False
```

doesn't do anything but clutter your code. Don't use that. Next up:

```
for i in range (10,10000,10):
```

Without looking at the project, be aware that range() yields all the values *less than* the stop value, so that would end at 9990. If that's what you want, fine - just be aware of it.

Finally:

```
    if [x for x in divisors if i % x == 0]:
```

That reads as "create a list of all the numbers in `divisors` that divide evenly into i", then "if the list I just created is not empty, then ...". So when `i == 10`, that list evaluates to `[2, 5, 10]`. That's not an empty list, so it evaluates to `True` and the `if` block runs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. There are a million of these to programming, and they are all blank to me at this point, so every one I can learn is a huge help. Appreciate it a lot. Hey, how can I make a for loop with no maximum bound? Replace the 10000 with some function for max integer value..

Comment: You can use [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for that, `for i in count(10, 10)` would give you a loop starting at `10` with a step of `10` that would run indefinitely (or at until you break, return, or an exception is raised).

Comment: Bingo. Looks better in my eyes, and it seems to have no impact on the convergence time so it's great.